# Header in my ionic application does not display

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i'm new in ionic framework, i'm trying to display global header with back button and toggle button and side menu, i did file menu.html and putted all of this here:

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="my-bar">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="icon ion-navicon button button-clear mybutton" menu-toggle="left"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menu"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
          Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
          Search
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
          Browse
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
          Playlists
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

but a i can't understand how to display it at my pages, here is my index.html:

```html
<body ng-app="starter">

    
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    
  </body>
```

and my another page feed.html:

```html
<ion-view>
 <div class="bar bar-subheader 
     item-input-inset bar-light mysearchbar">
     <label class="item-input-wrapper">
       <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
       <input type="search" ng-model="query" placeholder="Search">
     </label>
   </div>
 <ion-content class="has-subheader content">
  <ion-list>
   <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right
   item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/feed/details">
      <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/modular-motorola-project-ara1.jpg">
      <h2>Google's modular Ara phone d...</h2>
      <p>24.08.2015</p>
      <p>16:35</p>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right
   item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/feed/details">
      <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/modular-motorola-project-ara1.jpg">
      <h2>Google's modular Ara phone d...</h2>
      <p>24.08.2015</p>
      <p>16:35</p>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right
   item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/feed/details">
      <img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/modular-motorola-project-ara1.jpg">
      <h2>Google's modular Ara phone d...</h2>
      <p>24.08.2015</p>
      <p>16:35</p>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

when i'm adding in my feed.html this html code:

```html
 <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
     <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon mybutton"></button>
   </ion-nav-buttons>
```

i'm getting this error:
 'Controller 'ionNavBar', required by directive 'ionNavButtons', can't be found!'

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: also add your js file where you are declaring routes.

Comment: I've got js file with all routes

Comment: I meant add routes file code to your question, so we can see what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to format this code, so i will add my routes, and how my menu.html looks now

Comment: .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })

    .state('tabs.feed', {
      url: '/feed',
      views: {
        'feed-tab' : {
          templateUrl: 'templates/feed.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/feed');
})

Comment: This is how my side menu looks like:

Comment: <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>

Comment: Sorry it looks very bad without formating(

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to add this piece of code in `feed.html`

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon mybutton"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

You already have added

```
<ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="icon ion-navicon button button-clear mybutton" menu-toggle="left"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

in `menu.html`, any page with menu will have toggle button or back buttone automatically(in case you go further in navigation).

You want to add `menu.html` as menu , but in routes you are doing this

```
{ $stateProvider .state('tabs', { url: '/tab', abstract: true, templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html' })
```

Instead youd should do

```
{ $stateProvider .state('menu', { url: '/menu', abstract: true, templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html' })
```

and further change `feed` routes to

```
.state('menu.feed', {url: '/feed', views: {'feed-tab': {templateUrl: 'templates/feed.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'}}})
```

But as you have mixed tabs with menu scheme. I will suggest you to create new project with `ionic start myApp sidemenu` and see how sidemenu templating is done

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, i understand that menu.html has automatically toggle buttons, but i can't understand how make menu.html works, i added all this html code to menu.html, but is nowhere my header, what i should to do, to have them appear in index.html and feed.html?

Comment: what is code in class my-bar, which you are using in `<ion-nav-bar class="my-bar">`

Comment: make plunkr of your whole code. Then i will easily solve your problem.

Comment: @Wahtel i have edited my answer, you can see what wrong you were doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, this answer is very close, but as you can see i can't abandon tabs, because in tabs.html i've got all my app navigation, so in theme like i have i can't mix menu with tabs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87896/discussion-between-mudasser-ajaz-and-wahtel).